# AudioSessionGetProperty deprecated, how to know device is silenced

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudiosession, audiotoolbox

I'm trying to detect user's device is silenced or not ( button on the side of the phone ).
I found this method to detect this, but AudioSessionGetProperty is deprecated in iOS7.

```
- (BOOL)deviceIsSilenced {    
    CFStringRef state;
    UInt32 propertySize = sizeof(CFStringRef);
    OSStatus audioStatus = AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute, &propertySize, &state);
    if (audioStatus == kAudioSessionNoError) {
        NSLog(@"audio route: %@", state) // "Speaker" regardless of silent switch setting, but "Headphone" when my headphones are plugged in
        return (CFStringGetLength(state) <= 0);
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Anyone got a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Sound Switch](http://sharkfood.com/content/Developers/content/Sound%20Switch/), there is no public API to detect the state of the silent switch, but they provide a hack (using public APIs and therefore believed to be OK for Ap Store approval, but still to be treated with caution):

http://sharkfood.com/content/Developers/content/Sound%20Switch/